# Send pgp encrypted mail+attachment with javamail

Tags: java, encryption, jakarta-mail, pgp

is it possible to send a PGP encrypted/signed mail with JavaMail (javax.mail package)?

Is it also possible to encrypt attachments?

If so, could anybody give me pointers how to do this?

I have searched the API docs (https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/), found nothing.

Do I have to use external libraries for encryption? If so, where can I learn how to sign an email?

I'd be greatful for any hints!
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you'll need a thirdparty library. You can use JavaMail-Crypto as mentioned in the answer, or use our SecureBlackbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) and [JavaMail-Crypto](http://javamail-crypto.sourceforge.net/).